# Find by Field name not working for two filed but Working separately in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am having a strange problem

```
1. $userCartProduct = BackOrderCartProductTable::getInstance()->findOneBy('product_idAndback_order_id', array($product_id,$userCart->getId()));
2. $userCartProduct = BackOrderCartProductTable::getInstance()->findOneByProductIdAndBackOrderId($product_id,$userCart->getId());
```

Above those two no 1 is working fine but no.2 not working. Can anyone please define me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug the query that is used and see why its not working - from a first glance it looks like it should work. Note in the Doctrine Docs : > These are very limited magic finders and it is always recommended to expand your queries to be manually written DQL queries. These methods are meant for only quickly accessing single records, no relationships, and are good for prototyping code quickly.

Comment: Is "product_idAndback_order_id" the exact name of the column?

Comment: yes, one is product_id and other is back_order_id